# How do I get differing text alignments in the same div?

Tags: html, css

I have made this div:

```
<div id="MyDiv"><h>HeaderText</h><br>

            DivText

</div>
```

I want to have the HeaderText centralised and the DivText aligned left. Because its within the div, the HeaderText CSS `text-align: left;` contradicts the div CSS.

I want it to be in there so it keeps the background formatting, position etc of the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine. I'd suggest it's because you are using unknown tags `<h>` in your code

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="MyDiv">
  <h1>HeaderText</h1>

  DivText

</div>
```